# Path analysis with perfect fit (RMSEA = 0; df = 4; Chi-Square = 3.972) is that too good to be true?

Tags: goodness-of-fit, structural-equation-modeling, lavaan

I created my first path analysis model with lavaan. Despite having a big sample (N = 600) my robust analysis has a perfect fit. I'm a bit suspicicous when something is perfect when I am doing statistics: Are the fit values plausible?. Here is the lavaan output with the fit indices:

[image: Lavaan fit indices]

Maybe relevant: My dependent variable consists of ratio values with a lot of values being 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It's not perfect, perfect is chi-square = 0, SRMR = 0.

Look at the formulas for the various fit indices.

If your chi-square is less than your df, RMSEA will be zero.

Your CFI is actually 0.997 which is getting rounded up to 1.00.

However, your null model has 30 df, and your fitted model has 4 df - that tells me that you've estimated a *lot* of parameters, and that your model is pretty unparsimonious. Your fit is good, but the model that is being tested might not be as interesting as it could be.

Comment: Thx for your answer. I created my model in a way that I also can explore different relations. Thats why I estimated so many parameters.

Comment: What would be the approach to create a more interesting model?

Comment: A more interesting model (often) has more degrees of freedom. Sometimes an unparsimonious model is the best model you can have, because of the theory you want to test.